# Yeoman local NPM link doesn't download grunt dependencies

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to make my own Yeoman Generator, but for some reason if I'm developing and install it through npm link, and run yo generator-myproject it gets to the mocha testing, downloads bower dependencies of the mocha test unit and that's it.

I did the same with generator-webapp as a test.
So I cloned it from github :

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp

I just put it in another folder, changed the name in it's package.json and also did a npm link.

It does everything well, but doesn't download any dependencies or whatsoever...
Which it obviously needs to do, even for testing. Otherwise there is no use of this Yeoman Generator.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying about npm link. Do you have a repository we can clone? Also, are you sure git, npm and bower are installed and accessible on your machine?

Comment: Everything is installed correctly, and you can clone the existing generator-webapp where I linked to.

When I npm link that one locally (I do rename it, not to interfere with npm online one) it runs the test but quits after, not installing the actual bower dependencies, gruntfile, ....

Comment: What do you mean by "run the test". What is the test? How do you run it?

Comment: It's exactly the same like your generator (yeoman official generator) webapp.

It runs a mocha test on install.

(I'm a newbie with this, not exactly know what I'm doing yet)

Answer (score 1):

Yeoman unit test helper ([`RunContext`](http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html)) by default skip any install methods as it is taking forever and is a flakey process (npm might fail and then your tests will fail for a reason out of your control).

You shouldn't need the installation methods to run to unit test your generator.